# PayPal Adaptive Payments - Separating Payment across back end and client

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

I am using PayPals adaptive payments for chained payment processing.  I am able to successfully get a preapproval key by calling https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Preapproval.

My understanding is that when completing a pay request (https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay), that you can add the param &preapprovalkey=PA-a891asnk to do implicit authorization and prevent the user from having to enter their credentials and the payment will automatically complete.

My question is: Can the 'Pay' process be split up?  In other words, I have a server process that already has the logic to create the receivers and the amounts and it calls 'pay' and returns a paymentKey.  If there wasn't already a preapproval, this paymentKey would be passed into the redirect and the user would enter their credentials.  Can I keep this server process and then just make a call back to PayPal passing in both the paymentKey and the preapprovalKey and do an implicit authorization?

When I tried this, it failed validation saying that the receiverList cannot be null.  I thought that the paymentKey would have this detail and I could just "approve" is using my preapproval key.

I realize many people would just ask why I wouldn't want it in a single call, but I want to keep anonymity between parties and have that logic stay on the server and want the client to just do the final "approval"

Possible?

Comment: Essentially, your question boils down to whether or not you can use preapproval keys with chained payments, and the answer is yes.

If you're getting some sort of error when you attempt that we would need to see a copy of the raw API request that you are sending to PayPal and the response that you are getting back.

Comment: I am not getting an error per se.  It is just that I want to make two separate calls.  One with the payment details and the chained payment details and receivers which returns a PaymentId and then a separate call using that paymentId and just the pre-approval to "approve" it.  The first call works fine and returns the paymentId, but when I try and send in just a "preapprovalKey" it says I need to pass in all of the recipients - which I don't want to do because it was already determined at the time I made the first call and got back the paymentId.  I will try and get sample request / response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it works is that you would make a call to Preapproval so that your payer can create the preapproval profile.  You would store that preapproval ID in your system with that user's details.

When submitting a delayed chained payment for that user you would call the Pay API with the preapproval ID included and the action set to PAY_PRIMARY. That is what makes it delayed.  You would include the primary and secondary receiver(s) details in this request, though.

With PAY_PRIMARY set the funds would go to the primary receiver only.  You would then make a call to the ExecutePayment API to trigger the secondary payment(s) when necessary.

Comment: Excellent.  That makes sense.  I already have the preapproval key and didn't understand the delayed payment.  So, the two ways to handle sound like calling the Pay API with the payKey and preapprovalKey in a single call, or, as you mentioned above using the PAY_PRIMARY and then ExecutePayment later.  Thank you!